Save Scroll Position SwiftUI
I'm currently using the posts to save the scroll position, but is there was way to save the exact scroll position so it stops jumping around and saves precisely.
 @State private var lastViewedPostId: String? {
        didSet {
            if let id = lastViewedPostId {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(id, forKey: "lastViewedPostId")
            }
        }
    }

ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
                    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                        LazyVStack(spacing: 14) {
                            if viewModel.posts.count > 0 {
                                ForEach(sortedPostsForYou) { post in
                                    PostCell(postWithUser: post, appData: appData)
                                        .id(post.id)
                                        .onAppear {
                                            lastViewedPostId = post.id
                                        }
                                }
                                .padding(.top, 17)
                                
                            } else {
                                LoadingModifier()
                                    .padding(.top, 230)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(0)
                    .onAppear {
                        if let savedId = lastViewedPostId {
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02) {
                                withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                                    scrollProxy.scrollTo(savedId, anchor: .center)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

I tried using the posts but it did not work smoothly.
